# Unable to see Rviz movement from odometry

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you diagnose why Rviz isn't showing any movement from when your robot publishes odometry messages?

I have a simple Python node collecting encoder counts and converting them to odometry messages, which I adapted from [this example](http://answers.ros.org/question/11973/gathering-wheel-encoder-data-and-publishing-on-the-odom-topic/):

```
class WheelTrackerNode(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self._PreviousLeftEncoderCounts = None
        self._PreviousRightEncoderCounts = None
        
        self.x = 0.
        self.y = 0.
        self.th = 0.
        
        self.vx = 0.
        self.vy = 0.
        self.vth = 0.
        
        self.deltaLeft = 0
        self.deltaRight = 0
        
        self.odom_pub = rospy.Publisher('odom', Odometry, queue_size=10)
        
        #self.odom_broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        self.odom_broadcaster = tf2_ros.TransformBroadcaster()
        
        self.last_time = None
        
    def update_left(self, count):
        """
        Called when the left encoder generates a tick.
        """
        if self._PreviousLeftEncoderCounts is not None:
            self.deltaLeft = count - self._PreviousLeftEncoderCounts
            self.vx = self.deltaLeft * DistancePerCount
            self.update()
        self._PreviousLeftEncoderCounts = count
        
    def update_right(self, count):
        """
        Called when the right encoder generates a tick.
        """
        if self._PreviousRightEncoderCounts is not None:
            self.deltaRight = count - self._PreviousRightEncoderCounts
            self.vy = self.deltaRight * DistancePerCount
            self.update()
        self._PreviousRightEncoderCounts = count
        
    def update(self):
        
        self.current_time = rospy.Time.now()
        if self.last_time is not None:
            
            # compute odometry in a typical way given the velocities of the robot
            dt = (self.current_time - self.last_time).to_sec()
            delta_x = (self.vx * cos(self.th) - self.vy * sin(self.th)) * dt
            delta_y = (self.vx * sin(self.th) + self.vy * cos(self.th)) * dt
            delta_th = self.vth * dt
        
            self.x += delta_x
            self.y += delta_y
            self.th += delta_th
        
            # since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from yaw
            #geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);
            odom_quat = Quaternion(*tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, self.th))
        
            # first, we'll publish the transform over tf
            #geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
            odom_trans = TransformStamped()
            odom_trans.header.stamp = self.current_time
            odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom"
            odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link"
            odom_trans.transform.translation.x = self.x
            odom_trans.transform.translation.y = self.y
            odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0
            odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat
        
            # send the transform
            self.odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans)
        
            # next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
            #nav_msgs::Odometry odom
            odom = Odometry()
            odom.header.stamp = self.current_time
            odom.header.frame_id = "odom"
        
            # set the position
            odom.pose.pose.position.x = self.x
            odom.pose.pose.position.y = self.y
            odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
            odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat
        
            # set the velocity
            odom.child_frame_id = "base_link"
            odom.twist.twist.linear.x = self.vx
            odom.twist.twist.linear.y = self.vy
            odom.twist.twist.angular.z = self.vth
        
            # publish the message
            self.odom_pub.publish(odom)
    
        self.last_time = self.current_time
```

I've confirmed this works by running `rostopic echo /odom` when my encoders are turning and seeing messages like:

```
header: 
  seq: 600
  stamp: 
    secs: 1481599927
    nsecs: 382975101
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -345.517481299
      y: -529.732867745
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 3.40801269352
      y: 3.78668077058
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

However, when I view my robot in Rviz with:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="model" default="$(find mybot_description)/urdf/mybot.urdf.xacro"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true" />
  <arg name="rvizconfig" default="$(find mybot_description)/rviz/urdf.rviz" />

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(arg rvizconfig)" required="true" />

</launch>
```

the model stays fixed at the origin. My robot has a pan/tilt head, and if I move that, then that change is displayed, so I know Rviz is able to perceive TF messages. Why isn't Rviz perceiving TF messages involving the base_link?

This is a screengrab of my Rviz setup:

[image: image description]

The only issue I see is that there's an error with base_footprint, "No transform from [base_footprint] to [base_link]". Would that be causing this problem? My URDF contains this link, so I'm unsure why I'm getting this error. How would I fix this error?

My URDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="mybot">
    <xacro:include filename="$(find mybot_description)/urdf/materials.urdf.xacro" />
    <!-- dimensions in meters -->
    <xacro:property name="torso_radius" value="0.075" /><!-- 150 mm diameter = 75 mm radius -->
    <xacro:property name="torso_height" value="0.16" /><!-- 160 mm height -->
    <xacro:property name="neck_height" value="0.015" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_radius" value="0.008" />
    <xacro:property name="camera_thickness" value="0.005" />
    <xacro:property name="M_PI" value="3.141592653589793" />
    
    <link name="base_footprint">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.0001" />
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0001" />
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${torso_height}" radius="${torso_radius}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${torso_height/2}" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="red" />
        </visual>
    </link>
    
    <link name="neck">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${neck_height}" radius="${torso_radius}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 ${neck_height/2}" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="green" />
        </visual>
    </link>
    
    <link name="head">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${torso_radius}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="blue" />
        </visual>
    </link>
    
    <link name="camera">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${camera_thickness}" radius="${camera_radius}" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 90 0" />
            <material name="black" />
        </visual>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="footprint_to_base_link_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_footprint" />
        <child link="base_link" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="base_link_to_neck_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="neck" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${torso_height+neck_height}" rpy="0 ${M_PI} 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="neck_to_head_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="neck" />
        <child link="head" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 ${-(torso_radius)}" rpy="${M_PI/2} 0 ${M_PI}" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
        <limit lower="${(90-65)*M_PI/180}" upper="${(90+65)*M_PI/180}" effort="50" velocity="1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="head_to_camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="head" />
        <child link="camera" />
        <origin xyz="0 ${torso_radius} 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
    
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250543/unable-to-see-rviz-movement-from-odometry/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-21**:\

> ```
> position:
> ```

```
  x: -345.517481299
  y: -529.732867745
```

Not an answer, but just something to check: translations are always in meters in ROS, so this robot is over 300m away in X, and over half a kilometre in Y. Probably just test data, but perhaps check your scaling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `odom` as your fixed frame in rviz. It seems like it is set as `base_link`.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-12-25**:
This was the issue. After I switched it, I couldn't tell at first, since the line from odom to base_link wasn't showing due to an incorrect scale, but after I fixed the scaling, the base_link was in view, clearly showing the link change as odometry updated.

**Comment by [arifle](https://answers.ros.org/users/40531/arifle/) on 2020-02-14**:
@Cerin Hi, I have the same problem. What does the scale mean if I have values like this
seq: 2084
stamp:
secs: 1581670360
nsecs: 559353710
frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
pose:
position:
x: 0.00172806205228
y: 7.86562370791e-09
z: 0.0
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.0
w: 1.0
covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist:
twist: